# How to send Token in Header from View(ejs)

Tags: node.js, express

I want to send json web token in my header for further authentication.

Controller function:

```
module.exports.checkUser = (request, response) => {
    crudModel.verifyUser( (result) => {
        if (Array.isArray(result) && result.length > 0) {
            if(result[0].email == request.body.email && result[0].password == request.body.password){

                let jwtToken = jwt.sign({
                    email: result[0].email,
                    user_id: result[0].uid
                }, "mohit_pandey_1996", {
                    expiresIn: 300000
                });
                response.render('dashboardView', {data: jwtToken});
            }
        }else{
            console.log('Invalid Username or Password');
            response.render('errorView');
        }
    }, request.body);
}
```

View(ejs) :

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a href="/user/home?authorization=Bearer "+data>Home 
         <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use one of two commonly methods. I describe how to make it with fetch object, on client and express framework on server.

**1. Setting the token in the HttpOnly cookie**

In server controller

```js
module.exports.checkUser = (request, response) => {

    const { token = null } = (/token=(?<token>[^;]*)/.exec(request.headers.cookie) || {}).groups || {} // Or  better use  cookie-parser

    crudModel.verifyUser((result) => {
        if (Array.isArray(result) && result.length > 0) {
            if(result[0].email == request.body.email && result[0].password == request.body.password){
                let jwtToken = jwt.sign({
                    email: result[0].email,
                    user_id: result[0].uid
                }, "mohit_pandey_1996", {
                    expiresIn: 300000
                });


                response.cookie('token', jwtToken, { 
                    httpOnly: true,
                    // secure: true // - for secure, https only cookie
                });


                response.render('dashboardView'); // - now we don't need to appear token to the view, because it automatically appears in cookies in each request


            }

        } else {
            console.log('Invalid Username or Password');
            response.render('errorView');
        }

    }, token); // <- pass token


}
```

On the client side (on page), if you are use fetch for requests, you need to add the credentials parameter

```js
function makeRequest(url) {
    return fetch(url, {
      credentials: 'include'  
    })
}
```

More about pros and cons of this method you can read this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39833955/9051045

**2. Using token in request header with saving it into localStorage**

Example (client script) in html > head

```js
function makeRequest(url, method) {
    var jwtToken = localStorage.getItem('token')
    var headers = {}

    if(jwtToken) {
        headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + jwtToken
    }

    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: headers
    })
}
```

This function make request with token, when it was setup in localStorage

Your Controller function: (server)

```js
module.exports.checkUser = (request, response) => {
    var {token = ''} = (/Bearer\s+(?<token>.*)/.exec(request.get('Authorization') || '') || {}).groups || {}

    crudModel.verifyUser( (result) => {
        if (Array.isArray(result) && result.length > 0) {
            if(result[0].email == request.body.email && result[0].password == request.body.password){

                let jwtToken = jwt.sign({
                    email: result[0].email,
                    user_id: result[0].uid
                }, "mohit_pandey_1996", {
                    expiresIn: 300000
                });
                response.render('dashboardView', { token : jwtToken});
            }
        }else{
            console.log('Invalid Username or Password');
            response.render('errorView');
        }
    }, token); // <-pass token
}
```

View(ejs) :

```
<script>
    localStorage.setItem('token', "<%= JSON.stringify(token) %>"); // <- setup token into localStorage, (but i think it's not good place for that, and would be better get token with another authorization request)
</script>

<!-- Your code below -->
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a href="/user/home?authorization=Bearer "+data>Home 
         <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
    </a>
</li>
```